# calculate interest by day in real time

Tags: php

i am a creating a system where users can do investments and gain interest. Now i want to calculate interest per day in real time, so the interest accumulate by day until the end date . I want this to be in real time, meaning i want to calculate the interest and up until the end date but my code only displays the results all at once. For instance if the start day is monday and end date is is friday the code should accumulate the interest everyday until friday in real time.

```php
$interest = 89;
$startdate = '2022-06-06';
$enddate = '2023-06-04'
$days = (($enddate - $startdate) / 60 / 60 / 24);
$previousday = date('Y/m/d',strtotime("-1 days"));
$currentdate = date('Y/m/d');
$totalEarning = 0;
$Earningsbyday = [];
if ($startdate <= $enddate && $previousday < $currentdate ) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
        $totalEarning  += $interest;
        $Earningsbyday[$i] = $totalEarning;
    }
        echo var_dump($Earningsbyday)."\n"."\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Can this not just be as simple as using `date_diff` and `array_sum` after combing the interests? [See it working over at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fmQsJ). If you want to calculate earning on day, wrap an `array_map` onto it...

Comment: Be careful with timestamps. '2022-06-06' is a string and `($enddate - $startdate)` converts each string to a number for the substraction resulting in a `1` from 2023-2022 (the rest of the strings is ignored). Maybe look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_create_from_format.asp) as a starting point for time related functions.
BTW: var_dump returns void `print_r($Earningsbyday, true)` is closer what you want. In real output use neither of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite simply. First, use `create_date` to create a `DateTime` in PHP. With these two converted dates, we can pass it to `date_diff` and format the amount of days between the two dates.

From here, we can use `array_fill` to fill an array of `n`th days with the interest. The total is simply just the `array_sum`.

We can now `array_walk` and calculate the previous day + the current interest to build the array you're expecting.

```
class InterestCalculator
{
    private array $dailyInterest = [];
    private static int $interest = 89;
    
    public function calculateDailyInterest(string $start, string $end): array
    {
        $this->dailyInterest = array_fill(0, date_diff(date_create($start), date_create($end))->format('%a'), self::$interest);
        $total = array_sum($this->dailyInterest);
        
        array_walk($this->dailyInterest, function (int &$value, int $key): void {
            $value = ($this->dailyInterest[$key -1] ?? 0) + $value;
        });
        
        return compact('total') + ['dailyInterest' => $this->dailyInterest];
    }
}

// total => 32307, dailyInterest => [0 => 89, 1 => 178, 2 => 267, ....]
print_r((new InterestCalculator)->calculateDailyInterest('2022-06-06', '2023-06-04'));
```

References:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.compact.php

---

Hopefully, this completes what you need. Feel free to comment if I miss understood your question.

[See it working over at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9mNln)